# How to prevent Quora from collapsing answers when the page sits there

Tags: quora

I get the daily emails of "interesting questions with awesome answers", and I will routinely load up all the ones in new tabs, then delete the email. It's great about not doing anything in the background, if I've never clicked to the tab itself.

My issue is that some answers are quite long and in-depth, and sometimes I need to step away for work-related commitments, after I've started reading the answer. When I do step away, and the tab has been clicked on (i.e. I've "seen" it in my browser), it will reset and go back to the Quora homepage, completely losing my place in where I was! What's more, because I open multiple tabs of interesting things at a time, I can't search for what I was reading before.

**Is there a way to prevent Quora from closing the answer I'm reading if I were to accidentally step away?**

Comment: This sounds crazy - why would they do that?! How long do you have to "step away" for? I've just tried this with an idle tab for about 10+ minutes, but its just staying as-is. You could perhaps try disabling JavaScript (although that might break it completely)? The thought being that JavaScript is probably used to trigger the "refresh"?

Comment: Once I click the tab to give it focus in Firefox, wait about 10 to 20 minutes, and your progress is lost, even if you're scrolling as you're reading

Comment: I don't seem to be able to repeat this. Using Firefox, click on link in Quora email. Scrolled down page and left it for 30+ minutes. No reset/refresh. I am logged in to Quora. Have you tried another browser? Is it possible that a browser plugin is causing problems?

Comment: I guess that's my next step